# Override default Laravel EnsureEmailIsVerified middleware not firing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am building a rest api using Laravel 8. I want to override the default `EnsureEmailisVerified` middleware and move the code I have from the controller into that middleware.

The code I have in my login controller for checking if the email is verified is;

```php
if (!$user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation link to your email.'
    ], 422);
}
```

This works great, but I want to move this out of the controller, So I created a middleware and moved the code into it as follows;

```php
class EnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): mixed
    {
        if (! $request->user() ||
            ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
                ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation link to your email.'
            ], 422);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then in my `Kernel.php` file I added;

```php
'verified' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
```

and then my login route looks like so;

```php
Route::post('login', [Auth\AuthenticationController::class, 'login'])->middleware('verified');
```

The problem is that it is not firing at all ... When I hit the login route it doesn't seem to check if the email is verified and just logs the user in.

Comment: `$request->user()` will return null on middleware. In my case I have a `status` field on user table and i check with `if (auth()->user()->status == 0) { ... }`. you can use the `web` middleware on your route then you can use `auth()->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()` on your `verified` middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set middleware to run before the authentication route runs. However the authentication route is where the user is logged in. At the point the middleware runs, the authentication has not happened yet. You need to switch your middleware to one that runs after the main controller request:

```
class EnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): mixed
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        // $request->user() may also work
        if (auth()->check() &&
            (auth()->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
                !auth()->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
                auth()->logout();
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation link to your email.'
            ], 422);
        }
        return $response;

    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh that assumes im using Auth::attempt yeh? .... As Im using a rest API, i dont use that method to return the token. I just check the hashed passowrd

Comment: @CodeSauce for a better experience you should consider using an authentication guard that works with your authentication process (or implement one if you can't find one that works). Being able to use the `auth()` helper is very useful. At any rate in your case you somehow need to know that authentication was successful in the controller

Comment: I am using Sanctum ... Is that what you mean by a guard?

Comment: @CodeSauce yes Sanctum includes its own authentication guard which you should be using to ensure the `auth()` helper works correctly